# How can I strip dollar signs ($) from a field in Hive?

Tags: csv, hive

I'm trying to import a csv into Hive. I have a column which is a dollar value and is reported within the CSV as '$123,244.00.'  I would like to convert this value into a float in Hive.

So I've loaded the csv into a temporary table, treating that column as a string. Next I want to load it into the final table, and in the process convert that string into a float or decimal.

Any suggestions on the best way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
select float(regexp_replace(substr('$123,244.00', 2, length('$123,244.00')), ',', '')) from table;
```

You need to remove any commas as well as the dollar sign. You may find this link helpful as well: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Types#LanguageManualTypes-NumericTypes